# Pandas cannot read a file from a mapped network drive

Tags: pandas

I have a jupyter notebook where I am reading a csv file from a mapped network drive.
It used to work fine but now suddenly it is saying that file does not exist.

filepath='S:/python/cfg/CUR_YRMTH.csv'
file=pd.read_csv(filepath)

Error says the csv does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your path contains forward slashes instead of backward slashes. Check it. While I normally use forward slashes, I don't think that works after the drive letter. If using the drive letter, use the OS library to resolve the path first.